# Video card driver not working when dual-boot Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows 10 Pro

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, grub2, uefi

I have installed Windows 10 pro and Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on two hard drives.

Windows 10 was installed on hard drive 1,
Ubuntu 20.04 was installed on hard drive 2,
Both are installed on UEFI mode.

If I make the system boot from hard drive 1, windows 10 was the only boot option and windows works fine.
If I make the system boot from hard drive 2, a memu shows up so that I can choose to boot from Ubuntu or Windows. But the problem is that if I choose to boot windows 10, the video driver could not be detected, Windows decide that "basic video card driver" is the best driver available. Plus, the catalist control center reports that it failed to load the AMD driver.

What I'm having is a Asus F2a85-fm motherbord with a integrated video card as AMD Readeon HD 7660D.

I tried to find out if grub2 is loading a different efi file than windows boot manager but found that they are all loading the same efi file, /dev/sda2/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi. It seems like windows boot manager is loading the efi file in a different way than grub2 chainloading mothod. But what are the differences, and how do I tweak grub2 so it load the efi in the same way?

Another question is that does windows boot manager load video driver in kernel before continue booting, like grub2? I've tried to load video in the boot.cfg file for the windows entry but still no luck.

Anyone could point out a way that I can boot from either hard driver to Windows and have the video card working correctly?

Comment: It will be ideal if I can boot from hard drive 2. What I need anyway is that I want to have that boot menu so that I can choose freely on which OS I want to boot. Plus, when I choose windows, I need the video card driver working.
I can now get into my UEFI/BIOS firmware and change it to boot from hard drive 1, that way I will boot Windows with video card working, 
I can also change UEFI/BIOS to boot from hard drive 2 and choose to boot UBUNTU and that works fine too.
But I dont want to change my UEFI every time booting.Any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, Karel. But the first link is something to use when Ubuntu is NOT needed. I'm not in that scenario, I want Ubuntu. The second link talks about solution which I've already achieved. I can choose to boot to windows from the Grub boot menu, but video card does not work after successfully booting to Windows,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

The solution was to add a new video adapter card.

I'm guessing that Grub was not able to load driver of my motherboard integrated video adapter card, and thus left a mess of video card driver. Then, when windows got booted in a chain loaded way later, it does not know how to clean the mess.

It's like a hardware solution to a software problem. Sounds radiculous, but worked.

I have searched the Internet like crazy to solve this problem, but finnally solved it myself. My guess could be wrong, if there's anyone want to discuss it, I'd like to do so.

Hopefully if anyone else encounter the same problem as me, they could search and find this post and thus have one more clue to solve there problems.